# Can I set a logical operator inside an if statement depending on a variable (bool)? C#

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
        static int SearchWithCondition(List<MyClass> list, bool someBool)
        {
            MyClass found = list[0];
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (someBool)
                {
                    if (item.id < found.id)
                    {
                        found = item;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.id > found.id)
                    {
                        found = item;
                    }
                }
            }
            return found.id;
        }
```

As you can see someBool determines if it will search for smaller (<) or greater (>) that's the only difference. How can I make it less "ugly" and shorter? I tried to figure out how can I replace the operator in the if depending on the bool but I couldn't find out.

Comment: Just to check, do you definitely *never* want to match if the given ID is equal to the found ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to substitute the operator; you just need to select the correct comparison expression. There are a couple ways of doing this.

```
if ((someBool && item.id < found.id) || item.id > found.id)
{
    found = item;
}
```

Or, using the ternary operator:

```
if (someBool 
       ? item.id < found.id 
       : item.id > found.id)
{
    found = item;
}
```